# Directed Trees: Finding all the edges and vertices in a specific direction

Tags: trees

I am an electrical engineer without experience in graph theory. However, I have a problem which I believe can be solved by graph theory. We have a directed tree, such as the one below. We want to find all the vertices and edges starting from a vertex in a given direction. For instance, in the figure below, we want to identify the vertices and edges downward from vertex 1 (the red lines). Is there an algorithm to do this (preferably in MATLAB)? The edges have equal weight.

[image]

Comment: You can use any search algorithms such as BFS or DFS. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search